# max-width is removing the background color

Tags: html, css

Im having a problem with the max-width css its is removing the background color when i aplying it to the code. I have not seen this problem on other sides, plese help me.

Here is my css code:

```
.mainheader {
    width: 950px;
    height: 290px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.leftheader {
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 325px;
    float: left;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: -290px;
    display: block;
}
.rightheader {
    max-width: 325px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -290px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net with your full code (CSS + HTML) so we can take a deeper look

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/3Smvt/ @Itay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you probably also want to set a normal width. If it has no content in it will not have any width. So u should put a `width: 100%;` and `max-width:200px` for example.

Here is an example with only max-width: http://jsfiddle.net/r7yEJ/1/

and here is with max-width and width together: http://jsfiddle.net/r7yEJ/2/

UPDATED

http://jsfiddle.net/3Smvt/3/

JQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var $width =  ( $(window).width() - $('.mainheader').width() ) / 2;
    $('.leftheader, .rightheader').css('width', $width); 
});
```

Comment: tnx, but my pc monitor is 24 and when i try it on my laptom (17) it dont shrink.. @Chanckjh

Comment: what do u mean by shrink? And post your html pls.

Comment: the sides is not getting smaller

Comment: i dont think it's possible with css, so i have written a little code for u

Comment: not possible its on everyside. I want so when im in my `1900px wide` monitor the div is going to be `325px wide` but when im on my `800px wide` monitor its going to be like `162,5px wide`

Comment: what are u trying to do? i see that the side are all the same colors. Maybe u want make the body whitesmoke. Then everything outside of the content and such will be the same color.

Comment: i want so the left and right header is getting smaller in the widht when im on a smaller monitor but not the header. 325px is the max for the left and right header.

Comment: and that is what my code has done... resize the fiddle and it will be smaller or bigger.

Comment: when i refreze the side its getting messed up

Comment: u say messed up, but what happens? how does it look like?

Comment: the left and right header is not showing its 0px but the main header is showing

Comment: have you included the JQuery library?

Comment: its WORKING before the side gets refrezed